# Bazel: How to run py_binary to produce input files before testing

Tags: python, c++, testing, bazel

I have a `py_binary` rule like this:

```py
py_binary(
  name = "testInputs",
  srcs = ["testInputs.py"],
)
```

and a `cc_test` like this:

```py
cc_test(
  name = "test",
  src = ["test.cc"],
  data = [":testInputs"],
)
```

test.cc needs an input file next to it (say `input.txt`) that is generated by `testInputs.py`.
I want `testInputs` to get run and provide the input file to the `test`.

As mentioned [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/python.html#py_binary_examples), I tried to to depend on `testInputs` in the `data` section. But the test doesn't find the input file nearby.
Result of `tree bazel-out | grep -F input.txt` shows that even `testInput` rule has not run at all - since `input.txt` file not exists at all.

Answer (score 3):

`data = [":testInputs"]` on the `cc_test` will make the `py_binary` itself available to the `cc_test`, not anything the `py_binary` might produce when run.

You'll want something like this:

```
cc_test(
  name = "test",
  src = ["test.cc"],
  data = [":test_input.txt"],
)

genrule(
  name = "gen_test_inputs",
  tools = [":test_input_generator"],
  outs = ["test_input.txt"],
  cmd = "$(location :test_input_generator) $@"
)

py_binary(
  name = "test_input_generator",
  srcs = ["test_input_generator.py"],
)
```

Comment: It should work. But according to documentation, this situation is exactly mentioned! "If you want to **run** a `py_binary` from within another binary or test (for example, running a python binary to set up some mock resource from within a `java_test`) then the correct approach is to make the other binary or test depend on the `py_binary` in its data section." see [the link I mentioned above](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/python.html#py_binary_examples)

Comment: I guess that my mentioned scenario may not work as dependencies are not run, but just build! But so what does the doc above say?!

Comment: In `cmd` section, what is `$@` for?

Comment: The documentation describes making a binary available to another binary so that one can run the other. But what you're asking about is making the output of one binary available to another. To do that you'd need to either depend directly on the binary as you did in your post, and then manually run the binary in test.cc, or ask bazel to do it by putting a genrule between the two binary rules.

Comment: `$@` is a shortcut for "the path to the output file, if there is only one output". See https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genrule.cmd and https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/make-variables.html#predefined_genrule_variables